# Соединить имя файла и содержимое в QByteArray

Tags: qt, c++

Есть имя файла, переведенное в QByteArray.
Есть содержимое файла в QByteArray.

Как добавить имя файла, затем содержимое в единый QByteArray, чтобы их можно было потом распарсить?

Comment: лучше добавляйте в начало размер имени, потом имя, потом размер файла и собственно сам размер. Так будет и парсить легко.

Если же жалко 4 байт (но там можно и два в начале, скорее всего хватит), то можно имя файла отделить нулевым байтом от содержимого.

Answer (score 2):

Создание:

```
QByteArray create(const QByteArray &fname, const QByteArray &fdata) {
   QByteArray data;

   QBuffer buffer(&data);
   buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);

   QDataStream stream(&buffer);
   stream << fname << fdata;

   return data;
}
```

Парсинг:

```
void parse(QByteArray &data, QByteArray &fname, QByteArray &fdata) {
   QBuffer buffer(&data);
   buffer.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

   QDataStream stream(&buffer);
   stream >> fname >> fdata;
}
```

`QDataStream` внесёт в буфер два `QByteArray` раздельно. Можно без проблем сохранять одинаковые типы Qt-контейнеров, поскольку каждый так или иначе сохраняет свой собственный размер автоматом при сериализации.

Answer (score 0):

```
QByteArray fileContent;

...
fileContent.prepend(fileName);
```

Comment: Это понятно, как распарсить-то потом?